# Assign value to enum of struct type

Tags: rust

I would like to assign a value to the enum type. Here is the sample code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct A {
    val1: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct B {
    val2: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum C {
    A,
    B,
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = C::A;
    println!("X: {:?}", x);
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d8de3fad6776dc7d5c26d365a560734e)</sup>

Now, if I want to do something like:

```
x.val1 = 10
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why would you want to mutate an *enum*?

Comment: @JaredSmith - not sure if I follow your question. There are many reasons. One of them is - I find at run time what type I want the enum to contain. But at a later time want to assign it a value.

Comment: `C::A` is an enum variant with the name `A`, it is entirely independent of `struct A`, they just happen to have similar names.

Comment: Thanks, @loganfsmyth! 

I suppose the right way is to define it like `A(A)` and `B(B)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, `C::A` and `C::B` have no connection to `struct A` and `struct B`. You would need to add them as fields to connect the two:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum C {
    A(A),
    B(B),
}
```

With that change, you can modify `val1` by destructuring `C::A` and getting a `ref mut` reference, like so:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = C::A(A { val1: 5 });
    if let C::A(ref mut a) = x {
        a.val1 = 10;
    }
    println!("X: {:?}", x);
}
```

Output:

```
X: A(A { val1: 10 })
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0cd6f3a22a2e41436d021006fe708c89)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Looks like we both typed it at the same time! :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @loganfsmyth's suggestion:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct A {
    val1: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct B {
    val2: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum C {
    A(A),
    B(B),
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = C::A(A{val1: 10});
    println!("X: {:?}", x);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8d5adb1986c6637b18317117015a5c7d)

The key was that enums are defined with just random names. If it needs to be assigned a type, it should immediately follow it. https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html explains in later section.